# How to upload TestCafe results to TestRail account?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, testrail

What is the best way to upload my testcafe test results to TestRail?

I am using TestRail as a test management tool and I see there is no official reporter supported by TestCafe yet. Is there any library that does this and what changes do I need in my tests for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [testcafe-reporter-testrail-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-testrail-simple)

This reporter needs only 3 configuration parameters TestRail host, username, and password, and does the required backtracking to collect information like project id, suite id, etc that are required to publish the Test Run results to TestRail.

No need to rename/ append the TestRailCase ids into the test case name, just add the tag {testRailCaseId: CXXXXX} in the test meta and the reporter will pick up the info.

Easy and Clean!